# problems in my setters and getters

Tags: java

I am new to java. I had some issues with my code. When I started to write setters and getters I had issues. The two errors are:

> Illegal modifier for parameter getName; only final is permitted

and

> Void methods cannot return a value

This is my code:

```
public class Profile {

    private String name;
    private String dayOfBirth;
    private String townOfResidence;
    private String counrtyOfResidence;
    private String nationality;
    private String listOfInterests;
    private Profile listOfFriends;

    public Profile(String name, String dateOfBirth, String townOfResidence, String
            counrtyOfResidence, String nationality, String listOfInterests,
            Profile listOfFriends){ 

        this.name = name;
        this.dayOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.townOfResidence = townOfResidence;
        this.counrtyOfResidence = counrtyOfResidence;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.listOfInterests = listOfInterests;
        this.listOfFriends = listOfFriends;

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        public String getDateOfBirth(){
            return dateOfBirth;
        }

        public void setTownOfResidence(String town){
            this.townOfResidence = town;
        }

        public String getTownOfResidence(){
            return townOfResidence;
        }

        public void setNationality(String Nationality){
            this.nationality = nationality;
        }

        public String getNationality(){
            return nationality;
        }

        public void setlistOfInterests(String interests){
            this.listOfInterests = interests;
        }

        public String getlistOfInterests(){
            return listOfInterests;
        }

        public void setCounrtyOfResidence(String country){
            this.counrtyOfResidence = country;
        }

        public String getCounrtyOfResidence(){
            return counrtyOfResidence;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting getters and setters inside the constructor?

Comment: I never understood why people are down voting, such questions. He clearly said he needs help and mentioned he is new to java. SO actually needs more questions like this. Who said only Guru's can ask questions?

Comment: @BorislavStoilov Totally agree. People should understand that a lot of novice programmers join this site to get help. Don't expect them all to formulate perfect questions or don't expect them to ask something really difficult. Something that seems obvious to most experienced users could be a pain in the butt for a lot of newbies. Be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to format your code, you could note that you've introduced the accessors methods (getters and setters) before closing the constructor's body:

```
public class Profile {

    private String name;
    private String dayOfBirth;
    private String townOfResidence;
    private String counrtyOfResidence;
    private String nationality;
    private String listOfInterests;
    private Profile listOfFriends;

    public Profile(String name, String dateOfBirth, String townOfResidence, String
            counrtyOfResidence, String nationality, String listOfInterests
            , Profile listOfFriends) {

        this.name = name;
        this.dayOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.townOfResidence = townOfResidence;
        this.counrtyOfResidence = counrtyOfResidence;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.listOfInterests = listOfInterests;
        this.listOfFriends = listOfFriends;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDayOfBirth() {
        return dayOfBirth;

    }

    public void setTownOfResidence(String town) {
        this.townOfResidence = town;
    }

    public String getTownOfResidence() {
        return townOfResidence;
    }

    public void setNationality(String Nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setlistOfInterests(String interests) {
        this.listOfInterests = interests;
    }

    public String getlistOfInterests() {
        return listOfInterests;

    }

    public void setCounrtyOfResidence(String country) {
        this.counrtyOfResidence = country;
    }

    public String getCounrtyOfResidence() {
        return counrtyOfResidence;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ... anyway, that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your code.
Since it will be easier I will just give you the working version:

```
public class Profile {

    private String name;
    private String dayOfBirth;
    private String townOfResidence;
    private String counrtyOfResidence;
    private String nationality;
    private String listOfInterests;
    private Profile listOfFriends;

    public Profile(String name, String dateOfBirth, String townOfResidence, String counrtyOfResidence,
            String nationality, String listOfInterests, Profile listOfFriends) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dayOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.townOfResidence = townOfResidence;
        this.counrtyOfResidence = counrtyOfResidence;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.listOfInterests = listOfInterests;
        this.listOfFriends = listOfFriends;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dayOfBirth;
    }

    public void setTownOfResidence(String town) {
        this.townOfResidence = town;
    }

    public String getTownOfResidence() {
        return townOfResidence;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setlistOfInterests(String interests) {
        this.listOfInterests = interests;
    }

    public String getlistOfInterests() {
        return listOfInterests;
    }

    public void setCounrtyOfResidence(String country) {
        this.counrtyOfResidence = country;
    }

    public String getCounrtyOfResidence() {
        return counrtyOfResidence;
    }
}
```

1. You forgot to close the bracet of the constructor.
2. In setNationality you had this.nationality = nationality; which sets the member variable nationality to itself. The method notation should be public void `setNationality(String nationality)`
3. listOfFriends is not used, but that is not necessarily a problem.